# Get all of the text from a string after the first one sentence

Tags: php, string, preg-match

So Currently I am using this code to get the first sentence only out of a string

```
preg_match('/^([^.!?]*[\.!?]+){0,1}/', $text, $abstract);
```

Can you please help me on how to create another regular expression to get the remaining text or get the text after the first sentence only ?

Thanks

Comment: can you use `explode()` to break the string apart at the full-stops so that it's put into an array of sentences?

Comment: Problem is I don't really know how ... how shall I use a regular expression to display the rest of the text after the first sentence in a string ?

Comment: I don't understand your response. Are you saying you have to do this using a regular expression?

Comment: I did the previous using a regular expression which was a regular expression to display only the first three sentences of a string as quoted in the question but now I need something to get the rest of the content after the first sentence ;)

Comment: What I have suggested should achieve what you want though, so it may be worth giving this a go. Can you do this or do you have to do it with a regular expression?

Comment: I think I can use anything else beside a regular expression the problem is that I need an example as I dont know how to use the syntax....

Comment: ok, I think the examples are getting there by the look of it so I'll leave them to it, good luck : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the general idea using `explode()`:

```
<?php
$string = 'Sentence one. Sentence two. Sentence three. Sentence four.';
$sentences = explode(".", $string);
echo $sentences[0]; // echos 'Sentence one'
echo $sentences[1]; // echos ' Sentence two'
echo $sentences[2]; // echos ' Sentence three'
echo $sentences[3]; // echos ' Sentence four'
// The following demonstrates how to do what you're asking, but I'm not quite   
// sure what your specific use case is so adapt as necessary.
echo $sentences[0]; // echos 'Sentence one'
// to echo the remaining sentences do this
// start at 1 not 0 to skip the first sentence
for ($i = 1; $i < count($sentences); $i++)
{
    echo $sentences[$i];
}
```

Note that this will treat any '.' as the end of a sentence so it may not be suitable in all cases, for example if you have 'I.T.' mid-sentence. Therefore the regular expression may be a more appropriate solution if you need this level of accuracy. Just let me know if you have any questions. : )

Answer (score 1):

This might help you if you know how many sentences are exactly there in that string.

```
$str = "First Sentence.";
$str .= "Second Sentence. Third Sentence"; 
$result = explode(".",$str)[1].". ".explode(".",$str)[2];

echo $result;
```

> UPDATE

Final Answer >>

```
$str = "First Sentence.";
$str .= "Second Sentence. Third Sentence"; 
$extract = strpos($str, ".")+1;
$result = substr($str, $extract, strlen($str));


echo $result;
```

Comment: I think it's close but this is concatenating .... My problem is that Im getting the string from a database so the string will be sort of static.... My problem is that I want to get the string from the database and display only the text after the first sentence.... in other words hide the first sentence from the whole paragraph / string ;)

Comment: @Eric The answer has been edited above in the answer.

Comment: @Eric practice marking correct answer as "Accepted" or "Correct". It helps many.

Comment: I accepted an answer already like 7 hours ago @Kirs can you please tell me how to also mark correct for other answers ? Thanks for your help What I did is marked the closest answer to solution and voted up the others which helped me ;)